# Help with LWC Links to Record Pages

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm still learning LWC and I need some help.

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I've created an LWC that will display the Converted Account, Converted Contact, and Converted Opportunity that will display on the Lead record page.  The intent is when the Lead is converted, it will display the converted records (when they apply) so if the end user goes back to a 'Converted' lead they can see those three aforementioned records.  This is needed by the Leadership team that have no background knowledge other than the Lead is converted but do not know what they were converted to.  The problem I have is the I cannot get the record page links to work properly.  They seem to be links, but when clicked, they do not navigate to the record.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="converted-details">
        <p>
            Converted Account ID:
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={handleAccountClick}>
                {convertedAccountId}
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            Converted Contact ID:
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={handleContactClick}>
                {convertedContactId}
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            Converted Opportunity ID:
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={handleOpportunityClick}>
                {convertedOpportunityId}
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

const FIELDS = [
    'Lead.ConvertedAccountId',
    'Lead.ConvertedContactId',
    'Lead.ConvertedOpportunityId'
];

export default class LeadConversionDetails extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId; // The Lead's record ID

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    lead;

    get convertedAccountId() {
        return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, 'Lead.ConvertedAccountId');
    }

    get convertedContactId() {
        return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, 'Lead.ConvertedContactId');
    }

    get convertedOpportunityId() {
        return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, 'Lead.ConvertedOpportunityId');
    }

    handleAccountClick() {
        this.navigateToRecord(this.convertedAccountId, 'Account');
    }

    handleContactClick() {
        this.navigateToRecord(this.convertedContactId, 'Contact');
    }

    handleOpportunityClick() {
        this.navigateToRecord(this.convertedOpportunityId, 'Opportunity');
    }


    navigateToRecord(recordId) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: "Account",
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Desired result would be, when an Account, Contact, or Opportunity is converted, the links will display and when clicked will navigate to the respective record.  In it's current state, when I click the links it does nothing at all.

What am I missing?  Please help.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your this method

```
navigateToRecord(recordId) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: "Account",
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

here you are using

```
recordId: this.recordId,
```

which ideally should be

```
recordId: recordId,
```

as you are passing the recordId as parameter, when you use this.recordId, it consider the current record id of the page you open

also, while calling you are passing two parameter, but defined one

so change your method to like this:-

```
navigateToRecord(recordId, objectname) {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: recordId,
                    objectApiName: objectname,
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the follow up on this!  I made those adjustments and deployed them in my sandbox.  However, the links still do not re-direct to the specific record page.  The recordIds display as a hyperlink, but when clicked, it simply does nothing.  When I hover over the link itself, it displays "javascript:void(0)" in the bottom left corner of my browser.  I'm using Google Chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: I reviewed this again and I missed adding 'objectname' to the navigateToRecord section.  This did the trick.  Thank you!